# copy a subset of files from a current folder to two different destination folders after numerical sorting

Tags: r, file, sorting, file-management, file-manipulation

I need to copy a sub-set of files from one folder to another, and repeat this process between multiple folders via R. My files are NetCDF files, where the file name convention is: letter "A" followed by YYYYDDD_(S)day.or.(N)night (DDD as julian date). eg: A2013001_N.nc, A2013032_S.nc, etc. The letter A is a constant for all file names from all folders. These files are located in a number of different folders. Each folder contains the same number of files (24). In copying, I want to sort the files in numeric ascending order, copy the first 18 files from the current folder to a new destination A and the rest of the files (bottom 6) to the destination folder B. I want to repeat this process for multiple folders.

I know that `gtools::mixedsort()` can order character strings containing embedded numbers enabling numerical sorting. I also know the use of use of `files.rename()`, `file.copy()`, and `fs::dir_copy` for copying files.

I am struggling on copying files based on a sorted order.

Comment: `vec <- vec[order(gsub("\\D","",vec))]` will sort a character vector `vec` based on anything numeric within them. From there, `head(vec,n=18)` gives you the first 18, and `tail(vec,n=-18)` and `vec[-(1:18)]` both give you all but the first 18. Lastly, since you already know the use of `file.copy`, then it should just be `file.copy(head(vec,18), destA)` and `file.copy(tail(vec,n=-18), destB)`.

Comment: I don't even think it's needed to do the `gsub`. The `order` function can handle alpha-sorts, and if all files start with A, the dates will be handled appropriately

Comment: @r2evans, thanks. I should've thought of `head()` and `tail()` functions. your answer should work. Thank you. Though like @42 pointed out, i might not need `gsub`, given the structure of the file names.

Comment: I was not assuming that the `A` is constant across all. If that is true then you're good. I did that solely because you wanted to sort them *"in numeric ascending order"*.

Comment: I just edited the question body for clarify. Yes, "A" is a constant for all file names. Still, the use of `gsub' will be warranted for more complicated or variable file naming conventions.